# Integration by parts: "math is broken"

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

just trying to solve a small example on integration by parts, and a weird thing happens: I come to an original expression increased by one. Please help me find out where the flaw is!

The task is to calculate the following indefinite integral:
$$
\int\tan^{-1}x\text{d}x
$$

Integration by parts formula (just in case):
$$
\int f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x) - \int f'(x)g(x)\text{d}x
$$

Let's expand our original integral:
$$
\int\tan^{-1}x\text{d}x = \int\cos x \sin^{-1}x\text{d}x
$$

If
$$
f(x) = \sin^{-1}x
$$
$$
g'(x) = \cos x
$$
then
$$
f'(x) = -\sin^{-2}x\cos x
$$
$$
g(x) = \sin x
$$

Applying integration by parts formula:
$$
\int\cos x \sin^{-1}x\text{d}x = \sin^{-1}x\sin x - \int-\sin^{-2}x\cos x\sin x\text{d}x = 1 + \int\tan^{-1}x\text{d}x 
$$

So, where have I made a mistake?

Comment: "Let's expand our integral". How did you do that expansion?

Comment: $\tan^{-1}(x)$ typically means $\arctan(x)$

Comment: @ZacharySelk Well, $\tan x = \sin x / \cos x$, and then we just flip the fraction.

Comment: Is $\tan^{-1}x=\cot x$ here? $\sin^{-1}x$ and $\cos^{-1}x$ means $\arcsin x$, $\arccos x$ each, which are inverses, not reciprocals of them.

Comment: I see you mean $(\tan(x))^{-1}$. That is an unusual notation

Comment: Note that even if you have written $\tan^{-1} x$ to mean $\cos x /\sin x$ you have defined $g'(x)=\cos x$ but later say then $g(x)=\cos x$ ...

Comment: @coffeemath Sorry, I mistyped! Let me do a correction. But in my calculations it's $\sin x$.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I suggest just writing $\frac1{\tan x}$ instead.

Comment: Ok, so $f^{-1}(x)$ actually means an inverse function! Thanks guys for telling me that! Well, but in this example, let's take $f^{-1}(x)=1/f(x)$, just amongst friends! I will take this into account in future, promise!

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right, but there are already a lot of comments regarding $f^{-1}(x)$ vs $(f(x))^{-1}$. They might be useful for someone like me.

Comment: Almost always, $f^n(x)$ refers to a function composed with itself $n$ times. (That is, $f^2(x)$ refers to $f(f(x))$, $f^{-1}(x)$ refers to the inverse of $f(x)$, $f^0(x)$ is the identity function of $x$...) The only exception is for *positive* powers of trig functions, in which case $\operatorname{trig}^n(x)$ = $(\operatorname{trig}(x))^n$.

Comment: @Deusovi Had no idea about $f^n(x)$. Was always thinking it's just a power of a result. Thanks for educating me!

Comment: To be frank, the notation you chose makes sense. It's just that the mathematics community as a whole has chosen the $f^{-1}(x)$ to denote the inverse, and not $f^I(x)$ or some other ilk of marking.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You haven't made a mistake.

Remember how integrals have " ${}+C$ " at the end? This is why. The ${}+C$ 'absorbs' all constants together into an unknown constant. Indefinite integrals don't give you a single function: they give you a *set* of functions that differ by a constant.

Comment: You're right! This makes sense.

Comment: This leads to seemingly absurd identity $\int f(x) dx - \int f(x) dx = C$, for any $C\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @tom That's because $\int f(x) dx$ isn't a single function, it's a family of functions, so you can't just equate it to a scalar constant and hope for any of it to make sense. Calculus notation can be rather treacherous due to this amorphous "+ C" constant so you need to be careful what you write. It's like the dx/dy of differential notation, it kinda behaves like a fraction but will mess you up if you forget what it really stands for.

Answer (score 6):

So, $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is not equal to $\dfrac{1}{\tan(x)}$. Instead, that is $\cot(x)$.

For the integration by parts, let $u=\tan^{-1}(x)$ and $dv=1\quad\!\!\!\!dx$

Remember that the formula is $uv-\int vdu$